# Can I specify an IP when connecting to a URL?

Tags: c#, sockets, httpwebrequest

I have a load balancer sitting on www.someurl.com, resolving to 100.100.100.100.  There are two servers being balanced: 100.100.100.101 and 100.100.100.102.  This is in order to create a health check which will make sure that the balanced sites are both alive.

Is there any way I can connect to the host www.someurl.com but specify which IP I want to actually connect to?  I am implementing this solution in C# and have looked into using HttpWebRequest and also Sockets.

Comment: If I understand correctly,  you're writing the back-end software that, when a user goes to www.someurl.com, you specify whether their request goes to .101 or .102? And that way you can load-balance?

Comment: The .101 and .102 servers are attached to the load balancer.  I want to connect to someurl.com but effectively skip the load balancer and hit each individual, load balanced server.  This is in order to do a health check.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have used two methods to accomplish this. First, you can use your hosts file to map the domain name to .101 or .102. Or, you can create new dns entires (www1.someurl.com and www2.someurl.com) that map to each server.

Let me know if you need more detail on either of these methods.

Comment: Is editing the DNS a good approach? Also, is the user typically able to change/edit the DNS?

Comment: You can create two entires in your hosts file. This is how I would do it. You can add dns entries if you need multiple people to have direct access to each server. No, the user cannot edit your dns entries. I have seen both approaches work.

Comment: For a monitoring scenario, I would add two new private dns entries. This way people outside your local network will not see them.

Answer (score 1):

> Is there any way I can connect to the host www.someurl.com but specify which IP I want to actually connect to?

If those IP addresses are publicly accessible from the client, then yes, you can directly specify the IP (`var request = WebRequest.Create("http://100.100.100.101");`). But I suspect that this is not your case. The IP addresses are not directly visible from where you are sending the request, only the load balancer is. In this case you can only send a request to this load balancer of course.